# Primes in $\mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been trying to proof that if $\pi\in Z[i]$ and $\pi$ is prime, then $\pi\overline \pi$ is a prime in $\mathbb Z$ or is the square of a prime  in $\mathbb Z$.

I took a prime $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ such that $\pi|p$, then $\overline \pi |p$, which is why $\pi\overline\pi |p^2$. I am stuck in that, so I need that $\pi\overline \pi=p^2,p$.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Well, what are the divisors of $p^2$?

Comment: They are $1,p$ and $p^2$

Comment: Have you shown that $\pi\overline{\pi}\in\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, I have shown it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that $\pi\overline{\pi}$ divides $p^2$ and that $\pi\overline{\pi}\in\Bbb{Z}$, so it remains to show that $\pi\overline{\pi}\neq1$. But this is clear because $\pi$ is prime, hence by definition it is not a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $\pi=a+bi$, $a,b$ integers.Suppose that it is a prime. First check  that $\bar\pi=a-bi$ is also a prime.

Let $n=|a+bi|=a^2+b^2$. Let $r$ be a prime dividing integer $n$. So $a^2\equiv -b^2 \mod r$. If $r\equiv 3\mod 4$, then the only possibility is that $a\equiv b\equiv 0\mod r$, so $n$ is divisible by $r^2$.

If $r\equiv 1 \mod 4$, then $r=c^2+d^2$ for some integers $c,d$, so $c+di | (a+bi)(a-bi)$ which contradicts the fact that $a+bi$ (hence $a-bi$) is prime.

So we need to consider only the case  that $n=m^2$ where $m$ is a product of primes $p_1...p_k$, each $p_i\equiv 3\mod 4$. Again, if $k>1$, then $p_1$ is a prime dividing the  product of two primes $(a+bi)(a-bi)$ which is impossible, so $k=1$.

Thus $n$ is either a prime or a square of a prime.

The opposite implication is obvious.